# How to display content in WebBrowser control with TrueType custom embedded fonts?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I want to display large amount of text, which is not possible in TextBlock because of height limitation.

This leaves two options:

- [ScrollableTextBlock (custom control)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx)
- WebBrowser control

The **ScrollableTextBlock** control is good indeed, the only limitation is the text cannnot be center align. But this is my requirement!

The **WebBrowser Control**, however, is a compromise. But there are lots of other issues.
 - The text is scrolling, even though there's only one line.
 - The height is a problem.
 - The bigest problem is the use of custom fonts, e.g., use of Asian Right-To-Left fonts.

**QUESTION**

- Could someone please tell me how can I use **Custom font with the WebBrowser control** to display text?

Thanks!

**Example** (How I was doing it):

```
   string str =  @"<html>
        <head>
            <style>
                @font-face {
                    font-family:my_font;

                    url('fonts/chFont.ttf') 
                    font-weight: normal;

                    font-style: normal;

                }

            </style>

            <meta charset=""utf-8"">
        </head>
        <body bgcolor='" + backgroungColor + @"'>
            <center><font style='font-family:my_font;' size='" + fontSize + "' face='" + fontFamily + @"' color='" + foregroundColor + @"'><p style='line-height:200%;'>" + strData + @"</p></font></center>
        </body>
    </html>"


   WebBrowser.NavigateToString(str);
```

Comment: I tried to use CSS (@font-face) inside the string I'm passing to NavigateToString() function. It doesn't work. The reason could be that I don't know how to use, or perhaps it just doesn't work in Wp7/c# WebBrowser Control.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to parse this code into Windows Phone HTML5 Application if you have SDK 8, just to know if it works. - This is necessary. And then try to replace path url('fonts/chFont.ttf')  with non-relative